# How do I push a merge to Gerrit from JetBrains WebStorm?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, merge, webstorm, gerrit

I am using git version 1.7.9.5 and WebStorm version 8.0.3.

I made a git branch called `merge-test`, pushed some changes to Gerrit, approved them, and then I merged those changes into the `dev` branch using WebStorm. The merge was successful, but when I try to push it from WebStorm (Ctrl+Shift+K dialog) I am getting this error in the Version Control console:

```
13:40:38.419: git push --progress origin dev:refs/for/dev
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done            
To ssh://user@gerrit.local:29418/MyProject
! [remote rejected] dev -> refs/for/dev (no new changes)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://user@gerrit.local:29418/MyProject'
```

When I type the exact same command in the terminal, I am getting the exact same error message. If I add `-n` at the end to the exact same command in the terminal (so the push isn't actually performed) this is what I am getting:

```
$ git push --progress origin dev:refs/for/dev -n
To ssh://user@gerrit.local:29418/MyProject
* [new branch]      dev -> refs/for/dev
```

And if I only do a `git push -n` then it shows that there are changes to be committed:

```
$ git push -n
To ssh://user@gerrit.local:29418/MyProject
    7332147..791ba19  dev -> dev
```

And if I perform the push, it is successful and what I expected.

How can make I push the merge from WebStorm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I should have only chosen "Push to Gerrit". The "Push current branch to alternative branch" checkbox was also checked by default; that must be unchecked to push merges to Gerrit.

[image]

Comment: i just downloaded webstorm 8.0.4. I don't see "Push to Gerrit" in the push dialog. Did i missed something?

Comment: @wang.aurora: You probably don't have a remote named `gerrit`. I later found out that "Push to Gerrit" doesn't appear unless you have that remote.

Comment: @wang.aurora: You need to install the Gerrit plugin in WebStorm.